# bogus component being added to WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms

Many times when I edit a WinForm in my (inherited*) project an instance of a particular component is added -- and I'm not intentionally doing anything to add it.  What could trigger the form designer to always think that a component needs to be added?

- *inherited project*: meaning that I didn't design/implement most of it.  There may be components or tools in use that I am not aware of.  It does use DotNetBar; but the component being auto-added is not from this library.

Comment: Never heard of this, it is certainly possible with custom designers.  Then again, never heard of 'inherited project' either.  This question needs more relevant and accurate info.

Comment: the term 'bogus' should be used more often in programming

Comment: @HansPassant -- inherited project: meaning that I didn't design/implement most of it.  Just now edited the question for clarity.   Thanks.

Comment: I think that special component is not for nothing, it's by design and used to do something. You can try removing all the related code to that special component in the auto-generated code file and see if there is any exception when running (or even at design time?)

Comment: Remove the references to that component.

Comment: Can you test this on another system?

Comment: It isn't happening in other projects.  It has happened in this project on other machines.  The components added had no references and were easy enough to delete.  Curious if some manual editing of InitializeComponent() could cause this kind of behavior.